# Quick Search of marketing list member in CRM 4.0

Tags: dynamics-crm

I need help in the quick search of marketing list member of CRM 4.0. When I do a quick search on the marketing list member, it only manage to search one column. Where else in account or contact view can I set it to search multiple columns?

Comment: can you do an "Advanced Find" against Marketing Lists in v4?  I am looking at my 2011 Online environment and I can do it there.

Comment: HI Glenn, i could use advance find in Marketing List. what i am mentioning is marketing list member. I need to do a quick search to search through all the column of the marketing list member . Please advise :) thanks

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you're trying to modify the quick find of the marketing list screen to let you search marketing list members?

Unfortunately, I don't think this is possible, since if you refer to the Marketing List entity, it has a separate N:N relationship to Accounts, Contacts, and Leads. Quick find only lets you search N:1 relationships on that entity.

You'll have to use Advanced Find to easily search this. If you create an advanced find view of marketing list, you can pull down the criteria and select the related Account/Contact/Lead and search by things like 'Name'. Then you can save the view and share it with users.